# Using inheritance to pass a non-static variable between classes

Tags: c++, class, variables, inheritance

I'm researching UI's as a portfolio project and I ran into a little bit of trouble when it comes to inheritance. The problem I'm facing is this: I have two classes, R_GUI, in which I draw the form, and Button, where I draw the buttons. I want the Buttons to be positioned inside the FORM. I store the FORM position as form_x, and form_y. Here are my two classes:

```
class R_GUI 
{

private:


    bool get_pos_only_once;
    bool move_form;

public:
    int form_x, form_y;
    int form_height, form_width;
    int handle_bar_y;

    inline void Form(int pos_x, int pos_y, int height, int width);
    //inline void Button(int id, string ButtonText, int pos_x, int pos_y);

    inline void Update_form(void);

    inline void UPDATE(void);

    inline ~R_GUI( );
    inline R_GUI( )
    {
        d3dInit();
        get_pos_only_once = false;
        move_form = false;
        form_x = 0;
        form_y = 0;
        handle_bar_y = 40;
    }
};
```

and the Button class:

```
class Button: public R_GUI
{

private:
    int b_form_x, b_form_y;
    int b_handle_y;
    int button_width, button_height;

public:
    inline void Draw(string ButtonText, int b_pos_x, int b_pos_y);
    Button()
    {

        b_form_x = R_GUI::form_x;
        b_form_y = R_GUI::form_y;
        b_handle_y = 20;

        button_width = 90;
        button_height = 35;
    }

    ~Button();



};
```

As you can see, I'm trying to give b_form_x the value of form_x (which is a variable from R_GUI). form_x has a value, given in Form( );:

```
inline void R_GUI::Form(int pos_x, int pos_y, int height, int width)
{
    if(get_pos_only_once == false)
    {
        form_x = pos_x;
        form_y = pos_y;
        form_height = height;
        form_width = width;

        get_pos_only_once = true;
    }

    //Create the form outline
    d3dLine(pos_x,pos_y,pos_x+width,pos_y,dbRGB(50,50,50));
    d3dLine(pos_x,pos_y,pos_x,pos_y+height,dbRGB(50,50,50));
    d3dLine(pos_x+width,pos_y,pos_x+width,pos_y+height,dbRGB(50,50,50));
    d3dLine(pos_x,pos_y+height,pos_x+width,pos_y+height,dbRGB(50,50,50));

    //Create the handle bar
    d3dLine(pos_x,pos_y+handle_bar_y,pos_x+width,pos_y+handle_bar_y,dbRGB(50,50,50));

    //Fill the Handlebar;
    d3dBox(pos_x,pos_y,pos_x+width,pos_y+handle_bar_y,dbRGB(3,3,3),dbRGB(3,3,3),dbRGB(3,3,3),dbRGB(3,3,3));


}
```

Yet, when I update the Form's Position, R_GUI::form_x value doesn't change. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to have a second variable in your subclass (`b_form_x`). Eliminate it entirely. Instead, you want to use `this->form_x`, which in the `Button` will be inherited from `R_GUI`. The same applies for `b_form_y`.

`this` refers to the current instance of an object, and contains not only your local member variables but also any member variables inherited from classes all the way up the hierarchy as well.

Comment: Hi @Borealid, thanks for the tip regarding this->. Um, the problem is that I update form_x/form_y when I update the Window, but the value remains unchanged in the Button class.

Comment: @BacioiuCiprian That's because they're different variables, and you've forgotten to copy from one to the other (specifically, you only do the copy in the constructor and not in `R_GUI::Form`). You want them to be the same, and not have that difficulty.

Comment: I'm updating form_x in the R_GUI::UpdateForm(), and I'm using this->form_x when I'm drawing the button (in Button::Draw() ).

Comment: @BacioiuCiprian I do not see an `UpdateForm` body.

Comment: this is the Update_form function: `inline void R_GUI::Update_form(void)
{
 if(dbMouseX() >= form_x && dbMouseX() <= form_x+form_width)
 {
  if(dbMouseY() >= form_y && dbMouseY() <= form_y+handle_bar_y)
  {
   if(dbMouseClick())
   {
    move_form = true;
   }
   else
   {
    move_form = false;
   }
  }
 }

 if(move_form == true)
 {
  form_x = dbMouseX()-form_width/2;
  form_y = dbMouseY();
 }
}
`

Comment: In Button::Draw, like this: `inline void Button::Draw(string ButtonText, int b_pos_x, int b_pos_y)
{
 b_form_x = this->form_x;
 b_form_y = this->form_y;

 d3dLine(b_form_x+b_pos_x,  b_handle_y+b_form_y+b_pos_y,  b_form_x+b_pos_x+button_width,  b_handle_y+b_form_y+b_pos_y);
 d3dLine(b_form_x+b_pos_x,  b_handle_y+b_form_y+b_pos_y,  b_form_x+b_pos_x,  b_handle_y+b_form_y+b_pos_y+button_height);
.......
}`

Comment: @BacioiuCiprian There is your problem. `b_pos_x` is a parameter to `Button::Draw`, but it is also a member variable of `Button`. The argument masks the member variable sharing its name. You need to use `this->b_pos_x` and `this->b_form_y` there.

Comment: b_pos_x is not a member of Button, it is only declared in the Draw function [`Button:Draw(string ButtonText, int b_pos_x, int b_pos_y);`]. Or, did I get answer wrong?

Comment: @BacioiuCiprian Right you are. I'm confusing `b_pos_x` and `b_form_x` now.

Comment: I replaced b_form_x/y directly with this->form_x/y for more readability. What keeps boggling my mind is why doesn't form_x update when I'm passing it. For debugging, I output the value in both Update_Form and in Button::Draw(). It shows the correct variable inside the Update_Form function, but in Button::Draw() it remains 0.

Comment: You misunderstand inheritance. The form has a different form_x than the button. So `b_form_x = this->form_x` in a button member function copies the button's `form_x` to `b_form_x`, not the form's! Hope this makes it clear.